# OnsenUiのリストボックス

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

タイトルの通りなのですがOnsen-uiでのリストボックスのようなものが探しているのですが見つけることができておりません。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

既にご確認なさっているかと思うのですが、ons-dialogのListではどうでしょうか？
（http://ja.onsen.io/guide/components.html#ons-alert-dialog　から少し下にスクロールさせた所に、「List」というサンプルがあります）

Comment: ありがとうございます！ 機能としては同じような感じなのでこちらを使わせていただきます。 大変助かりました！